# Can anyone help me solve this python code for login email

Tags: python, p-lang

I try to write a code for login email with website but the browser open but username and password not work fillout the input

```
def open_browser(self):
    # Open the browser processes for each profile directory
    url = self.txt_weblink.text()
    # Define the path to the Google Chrome executable
    chrome_path = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"

    # Define the first set of custom profile directories
    profile_directories_1 = [self.txt_path1.text()]
    # Open the browser processes for each profile directory
    browser_processes = []
    for directory in profile_directories_1:
        process = subprocess.Popen(
            [chrome_path, directory, url, "--windows=350, 600", "--position=0, 0",
                "--start-minimized",
                "--webbrowser=3", "--tab=3"])
        browser_processes.append(process)
def Login_outlook_subprocess(self):
    username = self.txt_email1.text()
    password = self.txt_pass1.text()
    self.browser.find_element(username='loginfmt').send_keys(username)
    time.sleep(3)
    field = self.browser.find_element(password='passwd')
    field.send_keys(password)
    time.sleep(3)
def click_button(self, by: By, value: str):
    button = self.browser.find_element(by=by, value=value)
    button.click()
    time.sleep(3)`your text`
def close_browser(self):
    self.browser.stop()
```

I try to make automatic login outlook email on chrome_path

Comment: Welcome to [so]. We don't provide general debugging services. We can assist with specific issues. Please use the following references on debugging your code to narrow your problem to a specific issue. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)